# GOOGLE TRANSLATE - translated -> original texts connections?

Tags: google-translate, translate, google-translator-toolkit

I HAVE A BIG DOCUMENT FOR TRANSLATE,
AND I'M TRYING TO SEE THE EXACTLY CHANGES FOR EACH TEXT'S TRANSLATION.

- Using **Google Translate** (API), The
  Translate **returns only the translated text**.

  1. Any way the get **"side to side"** that connection between the the source words & translated words?
  2. *if isn't, is there a different API for it?

---

**POST EXAMPLE:**
`https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2q=Hi%20Hello,%20How%20are%20you?&v=2.0&source=en&target=ja&key=...`

**ORIGINAL RESPONSE:**

```
json:
 {
    data =     {
        translations =         (
                        {
                translatedText = "\U3053\U3093\U306b\U3061\U306f\U3001\U5143\U6c17\Uff1f";        

            }
        );
    };
}
```

**GOAL RESPONSE:**

```
translatedText = "\U3053\U3093\U306b";    
sourceText = "Hello";** 


translatedText = "\U3053\U3093\U306b\U3061\";    
sourceText = "How are you?";**
```

Comment: Which rest  client are you using?

Comment: @Alexander.Furer, POST (Example url in the question)

Comment: @Alexander.Furer IOS